# OpenGL Third Person Camera cant combine axes correctly

Tags: java, opengl, 3d

I try to implement a Third person camera in OpenGL and seem to be almost done. I can rotate around the `y` axis and the `x+z` axis. But when I try both at once it doesn't looks good because he doesn't look at the object anymore. Can you figure out where the mistake is? Heres the code:

```
glTranslatef(world.player.x-4.5f,world.player.y-4.5f,world.player.z-20f-4.5f);

modelHandler.modelList.get("TEST").render();

double camerax = 20 * Math.cos((world.player.getYaw() + 270.0f) * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(world.player.getPitch())) + world.player.x;
double cameray = 20 * Math.sin((world.player.getPitch()) * Math.PI / 180) + world.player.y;
double cameraz = 20 * Math.sin((world.player.getYaw() - 270.0f) * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(world.player.getPitch())) + world.player.z-20;


glRotatef(360.0f - world.player.getYaw(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(world.player.getPitch() * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(360.0f - world.player.getYaw())), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(world.player.getPitch() * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(360.0f - world.player.getYaw())), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslated(-camerax, -cameray, -cameraz);

// render world and stuff
```

Comment: Why not use LookAt() function instead?

Comment: Look at how this feature is implemented in some famous high level APIs, for example JMonkeyEngine.